# How can I add OS X “tags” to files programmatically, using dropbox api?

Tags: ios, macos, dropbox-api

I use SwiftyDropbox to upload files, I can add own metadata to file using properties api, but can I add values to com.apple.metadata:kMDItemOMUserTags? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately, [the Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers), which [SwiftyDropbox](https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox) uses, doesn't offer the ability to read or write macOS "tags" (which are stored as "extended attributes" also known as "xattrs").

The metadata exposed by default on the Dropbox API is only the Dropbox file metadata, and the file properties are only for custom defined Dropbox templates.

I'll pass this along as a feature request, but I can't promise if or when that might be implemented.